# Check if Outlook SenderEmailType is exchange and set variable

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I am trying to detect if an email is exchange or not.

Here is the code I have:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend

    Dim sendAddress As String

    If Item.SenderEmailType = "EX" Then
        sendAddress = Item.Sender.GetExchangeUser().PrimarySmtpAddress
    Else
        sendAddress = Item.SenderEmailAddress
    End If

    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(sendAddress)

End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object variable or With block variable not set.'

Any ideas why this is?

Comment: What is the type of item? Please add more relevant code.

Comment: Sorry, i have edited. Does that help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Object can be anything, guessing it does not have the properties you think it has, ie. ***Sender*** or ***SenderEmailAddress***. Debug the code and see which line throws the error and what does the item consist of. Also I recommend familiarising yourself with strongly typed classes and habits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535318/6375113) I think what you want is something like this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles application.ItemSend

    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(Item, Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim sender As Outlook.AddressEntry = mailItem.Sender
    Dim senderAddress As String = ""

    If sender IsNot Nothing AndAlso
       (sender.AddressEntryUserType = Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeAgentAddressEntry OrElse _
        sender.AddressEntryUserType = Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry) Then
        Dim exchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser = sender.GetExchangeUser()

        If exchangeUser IsNot Nothing Then
            senderAddress = exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()
        End If
    Else
        Dim recipient As Outlook.Recipient = application.Session.CreateRecipient(mailItem.SenderEmailAddress)
        If recipient IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim exchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
            If exchangeUser IsNot Nothing Then
                senderAddress = exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()
            End If
        End If

        'check if senderAddress has been set with above code. If not try SenderEmailAddress
        If senderAddress = "" Then
            senderAddress = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress()
        End If
    End If

    MessageBox.Show(senderAddress)

End Sub
```

First thing to note is that I'm casting the object `Item` to a `MailItem`. This is so I can correctly access the properties. I would suggest to you to turn [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx):

> Restricts implicit data type conversions to only widening conversions, disallows late binding, and disallows implicit typing that results in an Object type.

You may also want to check other `OlAddressEntryUserType`s but I'll leave that to you. This code *should* resolve your error at least.

However after reviewing the above code, I wonder if it is necessary, at least in the `Application.ItemSend` method. I believe this could be condensed a little to something like this:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean) Handles Application.ItemSend

    Dim mailItem As Outlook.MailItem = DirectCast(Item, Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim senderAddress As String = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress

    Dim recipient As Outlook.Recipient = Application.Session.CreateRecipient(senderAddress)
    If recipient IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim exchangeUser As Outlook.ExchangeUser = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
        If exchangeUser IsNot Nothing Then
            senderAddress = exchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress()
        End If
    End If

    MessageBox.Show(senderAddress)

End Sub
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks @bugs