# Get Email address from sender account

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

Is there a way to "read" the user E-Mail Address from Outlook Account which is logged in and send an E-Mail when I activate this Macro?

```
Sub MailSenden()

Dim olApp     As Object
Dim olOldBody As String

Rem Email erstellen
Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With olApp.CreateItem(0)
    .GetInspector.Display
    olOldBody = .htmlBody
    .To = "carsten.asdf@xxx.yy"
    .Subject = "Testformular"
    .Body = "Das ist eine e-Mail" & Chr(13) & _
            "Viele Grüße..." & Chr(13) & Chr(13)
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\" & Environ$("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\" & "CSV-Export.csv"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send

End With

Kill "C:\Users\" & Environ$("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\" & "CSV-Export.csv"


End Sub
```

I need to get the "from" E-Mail address.

EDIT1: Solution for smtp

```
Msgbox        
CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Session.CurrentUser. _
AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current user email address, please use following code.

```
With olApp
MsgBox .GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser.Address
End With
```

to choose from which address you will send your email, please use this code. This way you are getting `"FROM"` tab inserted in created email.

```
With olApp.CreateItem(0)
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "YourEmail@yourdomain.com"
    .GetInspector.Display
    olOldBody = .htmlBody
    .To = "carsten.asdf@xxx.yy"
    .Subject = "Testformular"
    .Body = "Das ist eine e-Mail" & Chr(13) & _
            "Viele Grüße..." & Chr(13) & Chr(13)
    .Attachments.Add "C:\Users\" & Environ$("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\" & "CSV-Export.csv"
    .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    .Send

End With
```

Please note that you should put `.SentOnBehalfOfName = "YourEmail@yourdomain.com"` right after `With olApp.CreateItem(0)` line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try `MailItem.Session.CurrentUser.Address` or `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress` both should work.

You may need to convert from an Exchange account to SMTP, to do this see:

[How can I get the sender email address using Outlook.MailItem in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361726/how-can-i-get-the-sender-email-address-using-outlook-mailitem-in-vb-net)